# Kafka consumer onmessage - api call makes multiple calls on each message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, kafka-consumer-api

Consider the following:

```
      const cached = this.cache.get(somekey);
      // console.log(!cached);
      if (!cached) {
        console.log(cached);
        return requestRetry({
          url: fullUri,
          json: true,
          maxAttempts: 3,   // (default) try 5 times
          retryDelay: 2000,  // (default) wait for 5s before trying again
          retryStrategy: requestRetry.RetryStrategies.HTTPOrNetworkError,
          fullResponse: true
        }).then((result) => {
           //do something with the result and return result
            this.cache.set(somekey, data);
            return result;
        }
     } else {
         //return cached result
     }
```

the above code is being called in the onmessage method of a kafka stream consumer. The issue I am facing is that if the result is not and cached is undefined it makes multiple calls to the url for each kafka message coming in.

How can make it such that only one call is made on the fist message coming in, it sets the cache and then on the next message its enters the else part and retrieves data from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `requestRetry` result promise in cache.
When it is resolved the cache would be updated with the exact result.